# Using method within rake file tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

A set of rake tasks of a `.rake` file are structured as follows

```
task :process_data  => :environment do
  CSV.foreach("scores.tsv", :col_sep => "\t", headers: true) do |row|
    begin
      [...]
       repeated_method_a
       ad-hoc_method
       repeated_method_b
    rescue StandardError => e
    end
  end
end
```

How should this rake file be structured to process sub-methods, such as:

```
def repeated_method_a
  do_its_thing
end
```

Comment: you can simply define this method on top of the tasks. Can you please check once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add it under your task in the same file, so you have this:

```
task :process_data  => :environment do
  CSV.foreach("scores.tsv", :col_sep => "\t", headers: true) do |row|
    begin
      [...]
       repeated_method_a
       ad-hoc_method
       repeated_method_b
    rescue StandardError => e
    end
  end
end

def repeated_method_a
  do_its_thing
end
```